# How to get most liked page on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook API to try and get the most number of likes for a Page.I am able to get particular page using page ID, But i want to show face book page ascending order based on most likes.

Comment: For all users? That's not possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only read/show likes of specific pages, but there is no (sorted) list for all of them.